# Android Socket BufferedReader readLine() not working when reading from the InputStream

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to loop code inside a thread in order to check for new data form the server periodically. I am using `InputStream.available()` in order to check if there are any bytes to be read. If so, I open a new Thread and try to read the data using `BufferedReader` and then log it to the console.

**In onCreate:**

```
HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("CheckForData");
                ht.start();
                Looper checkForDataLooper = ht.getLooper();
                checkForDataHandler = new Handler(checkForDataLooper);
                checkForDataHandler.post(checkForData);
```

**The two runnables:**

```
Runnable checkForData = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.d("Count", "run: " + inputStream.available());
                if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    checkForDataHandler.removeCallbacks(checkForData);
                    new Thread(parseData).start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "run: " + e);
            }
            checkForDataHandler.postDelayed(checkForData, 3000);
        }
    };
```

```
Runnable parseData = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    data.append(line);
                }
                Log.d("PARSED DATA", "run: " + data);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

**The console:**

```
D/Count: run: 0
D/AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=26256
D/Count: run: 0
D/Count: run: 0
D/Count: run: 4
D/Count: run: 0
D/Count: run: 0
D/Count: run: 0
D/Count: run: 0
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:215)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:291)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:355)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:181)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:172)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:335)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:400)
W/System.err:     at com.bitline.httpcomtest.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:121)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

The 5th line in the console represents the moment when I send some data from the server. I can see that the number of bytes in the InputStream modifies, then the BufferedReader consumes them, but the data isn't logged to the console.
The exception throws when I force close the server.

PS. I am new to threading and networking so I apologize if this is some rookie mistake I am making.

Thank you.

Comment: `data.append(line);` That should be `data.append(line).append("\n");`. In order to preserve the original lines if you have more then one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer:
The server wasn't sending `\n` or `\r` at the end of the data and `BufferedReader.readLine()` looks for one of these characters. As a result, the `InputStream` was being read endlessly.

Comment: In short: If the client tries to read a line the server should have sent one. And a line is a string ending with the newline character \n.